# Particular Solution of Multiple-Degree-of-Freedom Systems

Tags: vibration

I was going through some Vibration examples on how to solve multiple-degree-of-freedom systems and I have noticed that they usually assume a particular solution with just one trigonometric function (sine or cosine depending on the excitation force, and when there is none, they just assume sine) instead of the regular pair

$$x_p = A \cos{\omega t} + B \sin{\omega t}$$

I was wondering **why** they make this assumption and **when** it is allowed (2 questions).

Comment: assume as much as you want, we certainly can't stop you.  They are actually looking for specific modes that meet those forms- the simplest modes they can think of.  In reality, things are more complicated but can be modeled as superimpositions of simpler things.

Comment: But if I assume, I may be giving an incomplete solution, right? So there is no way of saying when should I assume it?

Comment: mathematical solutions are always incomplete compared to reality.  When it comes to vibration, you could mesh a very fine model and apply your excitation and simulate some results.  You can think of the parts as lots of springs.  question then is what is the minimum number that gets you adequate results?  It depends on the structure.  you can increase the number until a solution does not change by much (as is often the FEA approach).

Comment: not sure if this is what you're asking, but the sine's express odd functions, the cosines express even functions, I think that's one explanation of why both are necessary ....  as for when, the magnitude of x_p must be bounded (stable system, finite excitation), and besides that, I think also system must be LTI

Comment: Thanks for the insight guys. I will review all your comments and the answer below thoroughly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not explicitly stated, since you are considered partial solution then the problem considers an external excitation F of some sort.

If I understood correctly the question the reason why `a particular solution with just one trigonometric function` is assumed is that:

1. through the Fourier theorem any time series can be approximated by a summation of many sines/cosines
2. Using sine or cosine is not a problem because of the identity $\cos(\phi) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + \phi\right)$, and equally $\sin(\phi) = \cos\left( \phi-\frac{\pi}{2} \right)$. So choosing sine or cosine is not a problem
3. the Laplace transform (which is a very useful tool in those problems) is very simple.
4. the sum of $A\cdot \cos(\omega t) + B\cdot \sin (\omega t)  $, can be written as $A\cdot \sin(\omega t +\frac{\pi}{2}) + B\cdot \sin (\omega t)  \Rightarrow$, and therefore you have the some of two sines at different phases (0 and $\frac{\pi}{2}$), which is equal to a sine wave of the same frequency at a different phase.

---

So, the main reason - IMHO - is no.3 because it provides a *simple solution* (some might giggle at this statement)  through the Laplace transform, and that makes it an ideal candidate for textbooks and in-class paradigms.